# Mute mic while shortcut pressed in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microphone, mute

I want to have a global shortcut/script to mute my microphone (visible as input device), but only while pressed. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

One more requirement: it has to work without going out of fullscreen applications.

Comment: By "when pressed" do you mean only while you're actually holding down the physical key on the keyboard?

Comment: @cxw Exactly. Maybe something from autohotkey + toggling muting via 'nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 2 "Device name"'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it. Used nircmd + autohotkey combo:

```
#z::Run nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1 "Neumann BCM 104"
#z UP::Run nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 0 "Neumann BCM 104"
```

"UP" is a key unpressed event. Key combination here is "Windows+Z".

"Neumann BCM 104" is my device name (as in "Input Devices" in Windows).

Nircmd's mutesysvolume reference: http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/mutesysvolume.html

AutoHotkey's Run reference: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Run.htm