# Mic gets randomly muted

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

After every reboot my mic gets muted for some reason. I need to unmute it from:

`"systray -> volume -> rightclick -> Recording Devices -> select the second one (the nondefault one) -> Properties -> Levels -> click the icon with the red circle"`

Any way to remove the need for doing this after every reboot?

Or failing that, an easier way to unmute?

**Edit:** Now I've noticed that the problem appears to happen even without a reboot - the setting randomly gets reset. But as long as I keep that window with the red circle icon open, it seems to stay unmuted.

Maybe the muting happens whenever I close the laptop lid or something.

**Edit:** I found out a [workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/937789/mute-mic-while-shortcut-pressed-in-windows-7) letting me at least unmute in an easier way. The question how to fix the root issue still stands, though.

Comment: I can imagine how annoying this must be. Unfortunately, even though I have tried a lot of different settings, I have not found a way to alter this behavior. I personally do not have this issue, but I use my default microphone. Could you also try if this still happens if you make that microphone the default input device? What comes to mind for me is that your sound driver might misbehave in some situation. If that is what is happening here it will be difficult if not impossible to resolve this. You can of course try to update your audio drivers. Please refer to the manual for that.

Comment: As for a work-around solution, it might be possible to write a simple batch or PowerShell script to unmute your input device with a single 'DoubleClick'. Maybe someone else can try and write such a script for you, I would have to practice on it for a while first.